# How to handle HTTP Basic Authentication in AVURLAsset?

Tags: ios, http, basic-authentication, avplayer

I am trying to develop a custom movie player in iPhone using AVPlayer. But I am just wondering that if the m3u8 url response sends back an authentication challenge, how do I handle that. I do know about didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and NSURLConnection but no clue about how does it work in this context.

Any help is appreciated.

-Soumya

Comment: Have you tried adding the credentials to the user-info portion of the URL?  For example, http://username:password@host/path. I have not tested this but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've made a different approach to a similar issue as we had to comply with redirects in HTTP, too. We did the authentication in cookies and set them for a whole domain:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            kAuthCookieDomain, NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                            kAuthCookiePath, NSHTTPCookiePath,
                            kAuthCookieName, NSHTTPCookieName,
                            kAuthCookieValue, NSHTTPCookieValue,
                            kAuthCookieDiscard, NSHTTPCookieDiscard,
                           nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];  
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```